# Return none if value of combobox is null

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, combobox

The first combobox makes a query about the second one. But what happens if in the second the value is null?
That is why I try to create that if the value is null I put something like 'none'.

Try the following:

I try to retrieve the result list with an if condition. But I have the following error.

```
def combo_input_type(event=None):
    some_name = combo_maker.get()
    cursor.execute("SELECT t1.type FROM maker_types t1 INNER JOIN makers t2 ON t1.maker_id = t2.id WHERE maker_name = %s", [some_name])
    result = [rec[0] for rec in cursor]
    combo_type['value'] = result
    #combo_type.current(0)
    #return result
    ######TEST
    if result < list(1):
        return list("ff")
        combo_type.current(0)
    else:
        return result
        combo_type.current(0)
    ######TEST

#COMBO TYPE
```

Error :

```
if result < list(1):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Change to `if not result:`

Comment: You can use `cursor.rowcount` to check how many records are returned before doing other stuff.